# COPY failed: stat : no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I have a maven wrapper which build package my application and copy the deployables into new folder and then run it. I am getting this error.

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder102689450/app/q-runner/target/q-runner-0.0.1-runner.jar: no such file or directory

Why should the file searched in above location when I mentioned to copy from /app/.

My docker file is

```
 # docker build -f Dockerfile.build -t abc/notify-build .
    
    FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:ubi 
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    COPY ./ /app
    
    
    RUN chmod +x ./mvnw && \
    ./mvnw package
    
    
    ENV JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0
    
    COPY /app/target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar
    
    CMD java -jar /deployments/app.jar
```

Comment: The location shown in your error message is the docker build context, i.e. the one that is created from your `docker build <context>` command. You cannot copy anything that is outside of the context. Any source starting with `/` in your copy command is searched from the context root. You cannot either navigate out the context by using something like `../../../app/` which will fire an error.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I spend sometime understanding the build context. I have resolved the problem now. Please check  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed this into two stage build and solved it

```
#stage1
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:ubi as builder

RUN mkdir build
COPY . /build
WORKDIR /build

RUN chmod +x ./mvnw && \
./mvnw package

#stage2
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:ubi

COPY --from=builder /build/q-runner/target/lib/* /deployments/lib/

COPY --from=builder /build/q-runner/target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar

ENV JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0

CMD java -jar /deployments/app.jar
```